# Attiny85 Serial Transfer INT from Teensy 4.1

Tags: arduino, serial, potentiometer, teensy, attiny85

Goal: Transfer incoming Analog Pot Data into Attiny85, convert to INT and send it out to Teensy 4.1 to read.

I have programmed my ATTiny85 to handle a 7 Segment LED (partial code below).  It takes the incoming Analog Data from a 10k potentiometer and converts it to a number between 34 & 300.

I would like to send that converted numerical information to my Teensy 4.1, where it can read it and apply it to code written inside the Teensy.

Is there a simple way to send this information to the Teensy?

Here's the simple code inside the ATtiny85:

```
 // My 7 Segment - 4 Digit LED sketch //
// Created by Christopher Miller 2020 //

const int dataPin = 0;
const int latchPin = 4;
const int clockPin = 2;
const int potIn = A3;


volatile int potValue;
volatile int outputValue;
volatile int outPotValue;


//digits 1-9, empty and minus//
byte one = 0x9f; //0b10011111 active low
byte two = 0x25; //0b00100101 active low
byte three = 0x0d; //0b00001101 active low
byte four = 0x99; //0b10011001 active low 
byte five = 0x49; //0b01001001 active low
byte six = 0x41; //0b01000001 active low
byte seven = 0x1f; //0b00011111 active low
byte eight = 0x01;  //0b00000001 active low
byte nine = 0x19; //0b00011001 active low
byte zero = 0x03; //0b00000011 active low
byte minus = 0xfd; //0b11111101 active low
byte empty = 0xff; // 0b11111111 active low
byte emptyDP = 0xfe; //0b11111110 active low

//activating columns left to right - thousands/hundreds/tens/ones//
byte colOnes = 0x01; //0b00000001 active high
byte colTens = 0x02; //0b00000010 active high
byte colHund = 0x04; //0b00000100 active high
byte colThou = 0x08; //0b00001000 active high

void sevSeg2(int tempo)
{
     if(tempo == 301){tempo = 300;}
     unsigned char thousands  = int (tempo/1000);
     unsigned char hundreds  = int ((tempo/100)%10);
     unsigned char tens  = int ((tempo/10)%10);
     unsigned char ones  = int (tempo%10);
     
     unsigned int numOnes  = empty;
     unsigned int numTens  = empty;
     unsigned int numHunds = empty;
     unsigned int numThous = empty;

      if(ones == 1){numOnes = one;}
      if(ones == 2){numOnes = two;}
      if(ones == 3){numOnes = three;}
      if(ones == 4){numOnes = four;}
      if(ones == 5){numOnes = five;}
      if(ones == 6){numOnes = six;}
      if(ones == 7){numOnes = seven;}
      if(ones == 8){numOnes = eight;}    
      if(ones == 9){numOnes = nine;}
      if(ones == 0){numOnes = zero;}
      //if(ones < 1){numOnes = empty;}

      if(tens == 1){numTens = one;}
      if(tens == 2){numTens = two;}
      if(tens == 3){numTens = three;}
      if(tens == 4){numTens = four;}
      if(tens == 5){numTens = five;}
      if(tens == 6){numTens = six;}
      if(tens == 7){numTens = seven;}
      if(tens == 8){numTens = eight;}    
      if(tens == 9){numTens = nine;}
      if(tens == 0){numTens = zero;}
      if(tempo < 10){numTens = empty;}

      if(hundreds == 1){numHunds = one;}
      if(hundreds == 2){numHunds = two;}
      if(hundreds == 3){numHunds = three;}
      if(hundreds == 4){numHunds = four;}
      if(hundreds == 5){numHunds = five;}
      if(hundreds == 6){numHunds = six;}
      if(hundreds == 7){numHunds = seven;}
      if(hundreds == 8){numHunds = eight;}    
      if(hundreds == 9){numHunds = nine;}
      if(hundreds == 0){numHunds = zero;}
      if(tempo < 100){numHunds = empty;}

      if(thousands == 1){numThous = one;}
      if(thousands == 2){numThous = two;}
      if(thousands == 3){numThous = three;}
      if(thousands == 4){numThous = four;}
      if(thousands == 5){numThous = five;}
      if(thousands == 6){numThous = six;}
      if(thousands == 7){numThous = seven;}
      if(thousands == 8){numThous = eight;}    
      if(thousands == 9){numThous = nine;}
      if(thousands == 0){numThous = zero;}
      if(tempo < 1000){numThous = empty;}

     // else{num = empty;}

      digitalWrite (latchPin, LOW);
      shiftOut(dataPin, clockPin, MSBFIRST, colOnes);  
      shiftOut(dataPin, clockPin, MSBFIRST, numOnes);
      digitalWrite (latchPin, HIGH);
   

      digitalWrite (latchPin, LOW);
      shiftOut(dataPin, clockPin, MSBFIRST, colTens);
      shiftOut(dataPin, clockPin, MSBFIRST, numTens);
      digitalWrite (latchPin, HIGH);
     

      digitalWrite (latchPin, LOW);
      shiftOut(dataPin, clockPin, MSBFIRST, colHund);  
      shiftOut(dataPin, clockPin, MSBFIRST, numHunds);
      digitalWrite (latchPin, HIGH);
      

      digitalWrite (latchPin, LOW);
      shiftOut(dataPin, clockPin, MSBFIRST, colThou);
      shiftOut(dataPin, clockPin, MSBFIRST, numThous);
      digitalWrite (latchPin, HIGH);
      
    
}

void setup() {

pinMode (dataPin, OUTPUT);
pinMode (latchPin,OUTPUT);
pinMode (clockPin,OUTPUT);
pinMode (potIn,INPUT);

}


void loop() {
potValue = analogRead(potIn);
outputValue = potValue *.3;
if (outputValue < 34){outputValue = 34;}
if (outputValue >= 300){outputValue = 300;}

sevSeg2(outputValue);
}
```

// How do I transmit the outputValue or PotValue to be read by the Teensy 4.1?

Comment: Welcome to the forum, Chris!

While there are a number of ways to transfer data between microprocessors. the ATTiny85 has a limited number of I/O pins (6). We can guess you're already using one for the potentiometer input, but you say you are driving a 7-segment LED from it as well. How many pins are used for that? Or are you going to remove the display and drive that from the Teensy?

Comment: What do you mean by "convert to INT"? Your `outputValue` variable is already an `int`.

Comment: Since you seem to be using Arduino code, just Serial.println() it and hook the UART up to one on the Teensy, either print a decimal value with a newline or for a little more cleanliness a hex one with a newline.  But really it would make far, far more sense to throw away the ATtiny and just use the ADC in the Teensy!

Comment: Thanks Mark.  I knew I should have included the whole code.  (see below).  brhans, you're correct.  My 'convert to INT' was not the proper description.   I was just pointing out that I am processing the incoming data to another int, and would like to send that out to the Teensy.  Chris Stratton I will give that a go!    See code below:

Comment: I couldn't add the comment down here so I revised the original comment to include the entire ATTiny code.

Comment: Thanks for posting code, which shows you have 2 gpio pins still available. Look up the SoftwareSerial library for the attiny. You will only need 1 pin (for TX) connected by a single wire to a pin (for RX) in the Teensy but you must be sure to connect their grounds together also. If you can restrict your value range to 256 values you can get away with sending a single binary (not ASCII) character for each reading.

Comment: Wow! Thanks for the insight, Mark!  I didn't know about linking the 2 grounds to each other.  And yes, 256 will work fine.  In one my problem solving attempts, I tried just connecting the pot to both the Teensy and the ATtiny and wrote the same code, but they never matched.  Always off by about 50.  And the Teensy would max out at 1023 around 1/3 of a turn.   I will give this a go and report back!  Thanks again!

Comment: So, transmitting it to the Teensy in Binary:  I would imagine that I will code a translator from INT to Binary and send that over the Attiny85 TX line to the RX of the Teensy.  I am going to do a lot of trial and error but I'm guessing I'll have to make an array to receive each of the 0's or 1's and then a translator on the Teensy side to convert it back to an INT before using it in the teensy code.

Comment: Sadly, I have tried many different ways to make this work but have been unsuccessful.   I haven't been successful in transmitting any info from the ATtiny.